# Why are input channels for Conv2D limited to 1,3,4 with the tensor dimension limited to 4-D in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to pass data of shape `(n_samples,n_channels,height,width)` to my model which involves Conv2D as its first layer. Here `n_channels` is of length 128 (basically, I am trying to pass different time samples into different channels), so the length can go up or down as well. When I try to pass the tensor simply as input, it complains that:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Tensor must be 4-D with last dim 1, 3, or 4, not [60,128,9,9,1]
```

I tried to change the shape to something like `[60,9,9,128]`, but it gives the same error

I am trying to pass a bunch of images at once through the network. I thought it would be clever to lump them along the channel (since, hidden conv layers can accept multi-channel inputs). But, somehow the first conv layer seems unable to accept this tensor shape.

I can not understand, why the arrangement has been made so in tensorflow that only 1,3 or 4 channels can be passed, and how to workaround it.

PS: Since the tensorflow 2.2 release, I am using tensorflow.compat.v1 for my tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about tensorflow, but in Pytorch, you can use something like .squeeze() to eliminate the last dimension, and the size will become [60,128,9,9], then it should be good.